# Scaling multiple faces along their y axis

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: I want to scale down selected faces along their local y axis]

My goal is to have these faces scaled down so it's symmetrical, any help?
It should be a knob just for making clear my objective.

Answer (score 1):

Set your Transformation Orientation to 'Normal', your Pivot to 'Individual Origins', and then perform a scale in the Normal space using either <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>.. you'll be able to see the direction of the constraint .. I can't tell which it will be from this illustration. (Or if you want to make the extrusions shallower, that would be a translation..<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>)